# c++ class template structure for vector definition

Tags: c++

I am really new to c++ , I dont understand what  `SMatrix<T>(int M)` is doing in the program . I have searched a lot about constructors in class templates , but this is not the syntax . And as far as know , `sMatrix<T>` is a datatype. Below is the code .

```
#ifndef T_SIMPLE_MATRIX_H
#define T_SIMPLE_MATRIX_H

#include <vector>

template<class T>
class SMatrix {
  private:

    // Storage
    std::vector<T> v;

    int N;

  public:

    SMatrix<T>(int M){v.resize(M*M);N = M;}
    SMatrix<T>(){N = 0;}

    void resize(int M){
        v.resize(M*M);
        N = M;
    }

    int size(){
        return N;
    }


    // access matrix(r, c) (row and column)  for R/W operations
    T& operator() (int r, int c){
        return  v[N*r+c];
    }
    const T& operator()(int r, int c) const{
        return  v[N*r+c];
    }

};

#endif //
```

Comment: It's a `class` template. What's your question?

Comment: Should be `SMatrix(int M) : v(M*M), N(M) {}`

Answer (score 0):

Inside the class template, `SMatrix<T>` and `SMatrix` mean the same thing.

You can, and should, use

```
SMatrix(int M){v.resize(M*M);N = M;}
SMatrix(){N = 0;}
```

with the same semantics.